# Como cambio el nombre a un proyecto y su carpeta

Tags: android

Tengo creado proyectos con los que estoy haciendo pruebas, con nombres como `com.HorizontalScrollMenu-master_Documentos_1`, y algunos algo avanzados con varios módulos java, que pasos tengo que seguir para cambiar el nombre por ejemplo `com.Modelos.Documentos ?`

Por otro lado, la carpeta donde se está creando el proyecto en el disco duro, tiene el nombre **HorizontalScrollMenu-master**, cuando he cambiado el nombre a la carpeta, y lo he vuelto a ejecutar me muestra una ventana con el mensaje :

> *The moduloes below are not imported from Gradle anymore. Check those to be removed from the ide proect too:*

Dentro de la ventana marcada la opción **HorizontalScrollMenu-master**
no sé muy bien qué consecuencias puede tener a no importar es modulo, y si hay que marcar o no la opción que muestra.

Luego cuando se prueba la aplicación muestra este mensaje y no me deja probar la aplicación.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

yo no he quitado nada, solo he cambio el nombre.

tambien he probado lo que en otros post han comentado, `File > Settings > Build, Execution, Deployment > Instant Run`, a quitar esa opcion y luego ponerla, pero sigue mostrando el eror

**Editado**
Creo que la segunda parte parece funcionar, he eliminado el archivo slice_4.apk de esa carpeta, como no estoy muy seguro ya me diréis lo que entendéis mas de esto, si esta bien, o si me voy a encontrar luego con algún problema.

Gracias.

Answer (score 1):

No hagas eso, no le cambies el nombre externo directamente, cámbialo desde dentro de android studio, te aconsejo que vuelvas a poner todo como estaba si es posible y sigas los siguientes pasos:

```
1-Vete a la vista proyecto en android studio.
2-Click derecho en tu proyecto
3-Click en refactor
4-Click en rename
5-Escribe el nombre nuevo y dale a ok
```

Si quisieras cambiar también el nombre del paquete, el proceso es exactamente el mismo solo que harás click derecho en el paquete que se encuentra dentro del modulo de java, rename .etc

Comment: Tenia la carepta comprimda antes de eliminar el archivo por si me decíais que lo dejase, no se si es a esta vista la que dices http://funkyimg.com/i/2AzNL.png pero si le doy a renombrar package o directory solo me cambia la ultima parte donde tengo puesto Ducumentos, pero el texto qeue hay delante com.darwindeveloper lo sigue dejando, y la carpeta donde esta el proyecto no consigo cambiar el nombre.

Comment: claro, porque eso es el dominio y tu nombre de usuario, la ultima parte es el nombre en sí

Comment: entonces para cambiar el dominio que hay que hacer

Comment: bueno no se si conocéis otra forma que funcione pero he seguido estos pasos http://funkyimg.com/i/2AAfq.png y sigue apareciendo el dominio

Comment: Te recomiendo esta respuesta, te será de ayuda, sigue los pasos cuidadosamente y no tendrás problema: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33140432/is-it-possible-to-change-the-company-domain-name-in-android-studio-after-creatin

Comment: Hola @Reductor ha sido un poco desastroso el cambio, lo he realizado varias veces por si la primera fallo en algo, mira la imagen como lo ha dejado http://funkyimg.com/i/2AAEL.png, nada que ver con un cambio limpio, incluso palabra documentos la ha escrito mal, Feliz Navidad.